# Bootstrap 3.0 Text Disappears on refresh

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 3.0 as a template to create a website. The issue I'm having is that when you refresh the page all of the text disappears. It does not do it every time but 8/10 times it does. Here is the demo I have put on my website for you guys to check it out. http://dwayned.co/JSwebsite/

Please let me know if you have any questions or need to see any code.

Comment: Maybe it can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984543/google-chrome-bug-website-not-displaying-text

Comment: Scott. After looking again it looks as though it is only in chrome, I believe the link that was posted to a bug is the cause. Thank you for sharing. I searched but couldn't find anything related so I appreciate it!. I'll look into it more and see if I can fix it with those suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is quite messed up. Bootstrap structure should be like this...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            YOUR CONTENT HERE
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above example I've used one col-xs-12 class but you can use any combination of cols here as long as they add up to 12. See more on the Bootstrap grid system here in their docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

I also notice in your code you are using a span12 class but this is from Bootstrap v2 and not the new v3 which uses the col classes I've outlined in my example above.

Comment: Thank you for your comment on my html structure. I will attempt to fix the issue. Although I do not see how this has anything to do with the issue I posted about? If I'm wrong please correct me. I'm new to this so everyday is a learning curve hah.

Answer (score 0):

I found this existing thread that has a couple different answers referring to your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984543/google-chrome-bug-website-not-displaying-text